# Forgotten non default id & password

Tags: password, reset

I have a pi with Debian 7 which I have had working a while age. I now I find I can't log on. I am not sure if I changed password, but don't think I did. Can I reset password without loging in?

Answer (score 3):

Use another linux box where you have `root`, insert SD card and change `/etc/passwd` and/or `/etc/shadow` to whatever you like, like empty password or known password hash from another computer.